# How long it takes for the German embassy to remove my details from Database after I drop a mail to rk-info@banga.diplo.de

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, germany, schengen-visas

I had booked a slot for the German national visa at the Bangalore embassy for 15th May 2019, but couldn't attend due to personal problems. I didn't cancel it. When I tried to rebook on 11th June 2019, I got the error saying "the entry should be unique. A different appointment with the same entry was already made". I dropped a mail to 
rk-info@banga.diplo.de to remove the details from their database on the same day.

Today I still get the same error. Can somebody tell me how long do they take to remove my details so that I will be able to rebook. I tried approaching the German Embassy customer care, Bangalore but they said "It's not in their scope to know the cancellation".

Comment: If you applied through VFS Global, you should contact them to resolve this. It’s unlikely anyone on TSE can answer your question